# Vim: expanding lines with a custom pattern

Tags: regex, vim

Recording macros is fine, but I have this in my .vimrc, 
and I find it very useful:

```
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" ,p prepares and ,a applies a pattern
"    $x = array("@@@"=>"@@@");        (type ,p here)
"    text                             (type ,a here)
" gives you: 
"    $x = array("text"=>"text");
" and moves to the next line to repeat
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
nnoremap ,p "ryy
nnoremap ,a "edd"rPV:s/@@@/<C-r>e<Backspace>/g<CR>j
```

Once you are used to this, it's a lot faster (for me at least) than recording a macro.

My question is:

Could this be changed to recognize different parameters?  The current replace recognizes only one (the whole current line) and places it where the `@@@` are.

I would like to improve it to something like this:

```
$x = array("{{1}}"=>"{{2}}"); // {{3}}    (type ,p here)
key, value, some explanation              (type ,a here)
```

And using that, obtain something like:

```
$x = array("key"=>"value"); // some explanation
```

I'm not very fluent in vimscript or a regex so dynamic (I mean, capturing a variable number or strings).  Could someone point me out in the right direction?

Comment: You'll probably need to write a custom function--something involving a for loop and substitution--and call this function in your `,a` mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one line map works, but there should be more elegant solution:

```
nnoremap ,a :let li=split(getline('.'),', ')<cr><esc>dd"rP:s/{{1}}/\=li[0]/g\|s/{{2}}/\=li[1]/g\|s/{{3}}/\=li[2]/g<cr>
```

the `,p` mapping doesn't need to be changed.

[image]

**EDIT**

got sometime just now, this should work for your requirement:

you could put it in your .vimrc

```
function! Doit4u(vline)
    let o = @r
    let vlist = split(a:vline, ', ')
    for v in vlist
        let n = '{{'.(1+index(vlist,v)) .'}}'
        let o = substitute(o,n,v,'g')
    endfor  
    call setline(line("."),o)
endfunction 
nnoremap ,p "ryy
nnoremap ,a :call Doit4u(getline('.'))<cr>
```

Comment: Pretty close!
Let's say I want to allow a maximum of 6 parameters, but I want it to still work if there are less than 6.  How could I avoid the errors `list index out of range` and `invalid expression li[6]`?

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli then write a function, then map ,a to call the function. in function you could check the length of the list.

Comment: Ouch, I thought I could get away with something like <silent> (that did'n work, btw).  I will do what you suggest.  Thanks!

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli got some time just now, added the function to make the answer complete.

Comment: Thanks!  I was learning some vimscript.  Right now I was looking for the way to get and set the contents of the r register...

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but wouldn't this function replace @r?  That way it would work only once...

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli oh, I don't know that requirement, i could change it

Comment: Thanks!  I wish I could upvote more.  (wait, I can... open your profile, look for other really cool response of yours...)  ;)

Comment: How did you generate the animated gif, btw?

Comment: There's still an oddity: the expanded line adds a `^@` at the end.

Comment: I fixed it with: `substitute(o, "\n$", "", "")`